# ERROR XNA Framework VertexBuffer IndexBuffer usage

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, terrain

I am creating a game after working through a XNA 4.0 book. It will be 3D, but I am already stuck in creating the terrain...

UPDATE: Everything starting from here is an update...
Terrain Update:

```
public void Update(Matrix view, Matrix projection)
    {
        View = view;
        Projection = projection;
        World = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-Width / 2f, 0, Height / 2f);
    }
```

Terrain Draw:

```
public void Draw(GraphicsDevice g)
    {
        effect.CurrentTechnique = effect.Techniques["ColoredNoShading"];
        effect.Parameters["xView"].SetValue(View);
        effect.Parameters["xProjection"].SetValue(Projection);
        effect.Parameters["xWorld"].SetValue(World);
        foreach (EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
        {

            pass.Apply();
         //g.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, vertices, 0, vertices.Length, indices, 0, indices.Length / 3, VertexPositionColorNormal.VertexDeclaration);
          g.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0, vertices.Length, 0, indices.Length / 3);
        }
    }
```

The commented line is working, in the both cases I am able to see the terrain...
The following code is to initialize Vertex and Index Buffer:

```
private void SetUpVertices(GraphicsDevice g)
    {
        float currentH;
        int currentI;
        vertices = new VertexPositionColorNormal[Width * Height];
        for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
            {
                currentH = heightData[x,y];
                currentI = x + y * Width;
                vertices[currentI].Position = new Vector3(x, currentH , -y);
                if (currentH < minH + (maxH - minH) / 3)
                    vertices[currentI].Color = Color.ForestGreen;
                else if (currentH < maxH - (maxH - minH) / 3)
                    vertices[currentI].Color = Color.LawnGreen;
                else
                    vertices[currentI].Color = Color.White;
            }
        }
        SetUpIndices(g);
    }
    private void SetUpIndices(GraphicsDevice g)
    {
        indices = new int[(Width - 1) * (Height - 1) * 6];
        int counter = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < Height - 1; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < Width - 1; x++)
            {
                int lowerLeft = x + y * Width;
                int lowerRight = (x + 1) + y * Width;
                int topLeft = x + (y + 1) * Width;
                int topRight = (x + 1) + (y + 1) * Width;

                indices[counter++] = topLeft;
                indices[counter++] = lowerRight;
                indices[counter++] = lowerLeft;
                indices[counter++] = topLeft;
                indices[counter++] = topRight;
                indices[counter++] = lowerRight;
            }
        }
        SetUpNormals(g);
    }
    private void SetUpNormals(GraphicsDevice g)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
        {
            vertices[i].Normal = Vector3.Zero;
        }
        int[] index = new int[3];
        Vector3 s1, s2, n;
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length / 3; i++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
                index[y] = indices[i * 3 + y];
            s1 = vertices[index[0]].Position - vertices[index[2]].Position;
            s2 = vertices[index[0]].Position - vertices[index[1]].Position;
            n = Vector3.Cross(s1, s2);
            for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
            {
                vertices[index[y]].Normal += n;
                vertices[index[y]].Normal.Normalize();
            }
        }
        FillBuffers(g);
    }
    private void FillBuffers(GraphicsDevice g)
    {
        VertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(g, VertexPositionColorNormal.VertexDeclaration, vertices.Length, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
        VertexBuffer.SetData(vertices);
        IndexBuffer = new IndexBuffer(g, typeof(int), indices.Length, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
        IndexBuffer.SetData(indices);
        g.Indices = IndexBuffer;
        g.SetVertexBuffer(VertexBuffer);
    }
```

I don't think, that there is a mistake, because it is working with the other line. Might there be an error with the .fx file I am using. If you think so, I am going to switch to BasicEffects...
(You might notice, that the code is from http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/series1.php )

Thanks for your help...

Yours,
Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answer to [original revision of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14912716/1).)

You're not setting your vertex buffer and index buffer onto the graphics device. These two lines of code (untested) should do what you need:

```
g.GraphicsDevice.Indices = indexBuffer;
g.GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer);
```

Place them just after you set the parameters on your effect (`ef`), before the loop.

The vertex buffer provides the vertex declaration that the exception message is asking for.

---

**Edit after question update:** In your new version you're setting the vertex and index buffers - but it's in the wrong place. You need to set them onto the graphics device each frame. Your code would only work if nothing changes them after you set them in `FillBuffers`. But I'm guessing that stuff is being drawn outside your class's `Draw` method?

If that something else is a `SpriteBatch`, even *it* works using vertex buffers and index buffers. So it will reset your settings. (It's worth adding that it also sets render states - in which case you might need to see [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/06/18/spritebatch-and-renderstates-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx).)

Comment: Hi,
Thanks. I tried to tweak everything, but now it works. If I had the reputation I would smash the vote up :)

Comment: Sorry, false info...
Hi,
Thanks. I tried to tweak everything, but now the error is still quite the same: The current vertex declaration does not include all the elements required by the current vertex shader. Color0 is missing.
I am updateing the initial description....

Comment: @Reisi007 I think my first answer is right, and you've just set the vertex and index buffers in the wrong place. I've added an update with hopefully more info about what might be going on. Let me know if it still doesn't work :)